# Closed unit ball in $ L^2 ([0, 1]) $ intersect the set of $1$-Lipschitz functions is compact in the $ L^2 $ norm.

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness

Let $$K = \{f \in  L^2 ([0, 1])  \,\, | \,\, \|f\|_{L^2} \leq 1 \} $$$$ L = \{f:[0, 1] \to \mathbb C \,\, | \,\, |f(x) - f(y)| \leq |x - y| \,\, \forall x, y \in [0, 1]\} $$ The question is to show $ K \cap L $ is compact in $ L^2 ([0, 1]) $.

I have shown that both $ K $ and $ L $ are closed in $ L^2 ([0, 1]) $, and that $ K $ is *not* compact in $ L^2 ([0, 1]) $. As $ L^2 ([0, 1]) $ is complete in its norm, it would suffice to show that $ K \cap L $ is totally bounded, but I'm not sure how to begin proving this.

Comment: The first step could be to show that $K \cap L$ is a bounded subset of $C([0,1])$ (here one has to use the Lipschitz property as well as the boundedness of $K$ in $L^2([0,1])$). Next, the family of functions in $L$ is equicontinuous, so by the Ascoli-Arzelà theorem, $K \cap L$ is precompact in $C([0,1])$. Therefore, any sequence in $K\cap L$ has a subsequence convergent in $C([0,1])$, consequently in $L^2([0,1])$. Since the $L^2([0,1])$-norms of the elements of the subsequence are $\le 1$, the $L^2([0,1])$-norm of the limit is $\le 1$, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The set $K \cap L$ is uniformly bounded by $2$:

  Indeed, assume that $f \in K \cap L$ is such that $\left|f(t_0)\right| > 2$ for some $t \in [0,1]$. Then for any $t \in [0,1]$ we have
  $$2 - \left|f(t)\right|< \left|f(t_0)\right| - \left|f(t)\right|\le \left|f(t_0) - f(t)\right| \le |t_0 - t|$$

  Hence $\left|f(t)\right| > 2 - |t_0 - t| \ge 1$. 
  Now we would have
  $\int_0^1|f(t)|^2\,dt > 1$ which is a contradiction with $f \in K$.
- The set $K \cap L$ is equicontinuous. This is clear because all functions are $1$-Lipschitz.

Arzelà–Ascoli implies that every sequence in $K \cap L$ has a uniformly convergent subsequence, so it also converges in $L^2$.

We conclude that $K \cap L$ is compact.